# Android permission to new created folders

Tags: android, directory, storage, external

How do I add permissions to newly created folders?

Example: User takes a picture (with the camera). If the folder I want doesn't exist, it is created, and the picture is place in it. Can I protect the file/picture from user-deletion, and to only give permission to delete the whole folder?

Comment: @ChrisStratton yeah quick read. My bad - nice catch. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: Sir, care to give your feedback response?

Comment: There is no such permission unique to folder creation, only permission to write files in various places.  Fundamentally, folders are just special files which can contain other files.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i understood you, you want to create folders and put images in it, and have control over it.. `{` well you could do that, by saving the folder to the [internal](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) [storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) and only you have the permission to do I/O -(but not always there is a word called *rooting* ) `}`

Comment: Of course the user can bulk-clear all of an app's internal storage either from the settings menu, or by uninstalling the app entirely.  Remember, it's their device, not yours.

Comment: exactly! ..yep..but sometimes you feel you can take over @ChrisStratton